# Vysor app isn't working for chrome on windows 7

Tags: chrome-for-android, android-device-manager, multi-window

I referred [this site](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-control-your-android-device-from-chrome-with-vysor/) to install and run vysor app but it turns out that it needed a graphic card instead of using integrated graphic cards on my windows 7

there was solution on how come over this error[image: error on launching vysor app]

but that solution was only for the windows 10 users to turn on multiple displays and that option isn't available in windows 7 
help me please

Comment: https://github.com/koush/vysor.io/issues/124 it is related to WebGL i never got it work. but there is a nice alternative https://www.xda-developers.com/scrcpy-control-android-on-pc

Comment: Yes, scrcpy is a very good alternative. I recently tried it. Teamviewer also works fine but requires internet.